# Images and itemize in Beamer concurrently without jumping

Tags: beamer, graphics, itemize, pause, slideshow

I want images on the lower part of the slide to appear concurrently with the corresponding items in the itemize environment.

The working example below does this; however, the first image is centered on the first slide, but then changes place when the second image is in the slide. 
I want the image to stay where it is for the whole sequence of slides in the frame.

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Foo}
  Some sentence:
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<1,2,3> 
    Text1
  \item<2,3>
    Text2   
  \item<3>
    Text3
  \end{itemize}
  \centering
    \begin{figure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
        \includegraphics<1,2,3>[width=0.7\linewidth]{img1.png}%
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
        \includegraphics<2,3>[width=0.7\linewidth]{img2.png}%
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics<3>[width=0.7\linewidth]{img3.png}%
      \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

How to accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide a full MWE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! You can work with `\uncover`. As I do not have your images, I replaced them with some generic graphics that comes with most of the installations.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Foo}
  Some sentence:
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<1,2,3> 
    Text1
  \item<2,3>
    Text2   
  \item<3>
    Text3
  \end{itemize}
  \centering
    \begin{figure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
       \uncover<1,2,3>{\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-a.png}}%
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
       \uncover<2,3>{\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-b.png}}%
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
       \uncover<3>{\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-c.png}}%
      \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course one can apply the usual tricks to make the code shorter.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Foo}
  Some sentence:
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item
    Text1
  \item
    Text2   
  \item
    Text3
  \end{itemize}
  \centering
    \begin{figure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
       \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-a.png}%
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
       \uncover<2->{\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-b.png}}%
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
       \uncover<3>{\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-c.png}}%
      \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Strictly speaking you do not need the `subcaption` package either.

Comment: Thank you for this "example-image-a.png" thing! I didn't know how to give MWE with images. How did you create the animation?

Comment: (Will wait 24h before accepting, in the case someone has something else to add.)

Comment: I'm curious to know that too :-)